# What __tpdsc__ means in the C++ compilation error messages?

Tags: c++, clang, c++builder

What `__tpdsc__` means in the C++ compilation error messages?
For example:

```
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '__tpdsc__ ELicense' referenced from LICENSE.OBJ
```

I am using CLANG as C++ compiler.

I am asking what tpdsc means, not what "unresolved external" means since it is clear. tpdsc  is something that the compiler adds and I would like to know what it means.

My code is:

```
  class PACKAGE ELicense: public Exception
  {
     public:
        ELicense(int code);
        virtual __fastcall ~ELicense();
     private:
        int Code;
        String CodeToMessage(int code);

   };
```

tpdsc word is not used in the source however CLANG shows tpdsc before the `ELicense` class name. I am trying to figure out what it means. Then I expect to understand about what the compiler is complaining since the error message shows only the class name, not the function name. Also, I have double checked that all functions are implemented correctly in the cpp file.

Comment: nice, 5s to close question :-)

Comment: @mrtnj Don't you have a fav list with these links? :)

Comment: @OP _"since it is clear. tpdsc is something that the compiler adds"_ Sure? Does it happen with a _Hello World_ program? You are missing to give us enough information for getting a better answer.

Comment: It's not an exact duplicate.  `ELicense` is the unresolved symbol.  `__tpdsc__` is likely some kind of CLang symbol decorator or type designator.  Google provides no information on it.  I too would like to know what it means.

Comment: @kokokok  a) are you compiling for 32-bit or 64-bit? b) What happens if you remove `__fastcall__` from the destructor declaration? c) What is the definition of the symbol `PACKAGE`? d) Does the destructor declaration _exactly_ match the declaration of `Exception::~Exception`?

Comment: 32 bits. I have deleted the desctructor and same error.

Comment: @kokokok what do you mean with `deleted the destructor`? As in just set to `=delete` in the derived class or in the base-class as well? (edit: oh, sorry didn't see this was necro'd)

Comment: The fastcall convention is poorly standardized.  Clang normally uses two registers (ecx and edx) but Borland used 3 (also eax).  So you are surely seeing the attribute that says "Borland convention".  With the advantage that you'd get a linker error when modules disagree.  The "tp" could mean turbo pascal, the first Borland product that used fastcall, that's a guess.

Answer (score 0):

`__tpdsc__` seems to refer to the destructor of the class. If you are using the default destructor or implementing the destructor in the a header file, you can make this error go away by implementing the problematic destructor in a cpp file.

Since you already have the destructor implemented, problem might be that it is both `virtual` and `__fastcall`, but I don't know which one is correct in your case.